# in creating a 2d array in java, why does the second dimension make me use 2 instead of 1

Tags: java, arrays

This section of code is to create a 2d array

```
System.out.println("How many people do you want to add");
peopleadded = userinput.nextInt();
String[][] People = new String[peopleadded][2];
System.out.println("put your name in the array");
People[0][0] = userinput.next();
System.out.println("put your password in the array");
People[0][1] = userinput.next();
```

I can't use 1 in place of 2  because it will give me a error message. Why is that? Doesn't the counting start at 0?

Comment: `[2]` represents place for two elements count from 0, which means that elements will be indexed as `0` and `1`. If you change `[2]` to `[1]` it will create array for only one element, which means that index `1` will be invalid because it will try to access second element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating an array in java you need to specify the length of the array which in you case is 2. The indexes will then go from [0] to [length-1]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Array declaration works like this:

```
String[] myArray = new String [2];
```

This will create a array named myArray which can hold two string on 0th and 1st index.

While if you replace [2] with [1] it will create myArray which can hold one string only. So here when you try to insert a string on second element which does not exist using myArray[1] it will give you a error.

Comment: so basically, the number in the declaration ([2]) makes two indexs a 0 position and a 1 right? so that is why you have to put 2 because if you don't then there is no place to put the password (refering to my code).